# Tomcat application not responding with no logs

Tags: configuration, apache2, tomcat6, ajp

I have configured apache to froward request to tomcat.  following are my configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName ***
ServerAlias ***
ServerAlias ***


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =***
RewriteRule (.*) https://***/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =***
RewriteRule (.*) https://***/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =***
RewriteRule (.*) https://***/ [R]


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName ***
ServerAlias ***
ServerAlias ***

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/


SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/***.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/***.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/***.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

I am getting following error in apache log

```
[Sun Feb 26 23:28:28 2012] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost) failed   
[Sun Feb 26 23:28:28 2012] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)   
[Sun Feb 26 23:28:28 2012] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost   
[Sun Feb 26 23:28:29 2012] [error] proxy: AJP: disabled connection for (localhost) 
[Sun Feb 26 23:28:29 2012] [error] proxy: AJP: disabled connection for (localhost)
```

It works correct for some time then suddenly I am getting the following error

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

When I tried `netstat -antup | grep 8009` command I got the following

```
tcp        1      0 ::1:40293                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32434/httpd         
tcp        1      0 ::1:40288                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32430/httpd         
tcp        1      0 ::1:40289                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32429/httpd         
tcp        1      0 ::1:40294                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32622/httpd         
tcp        1      0 ::1:40292                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32435/httpd         
tcp        1      0 ::1:40290                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32436/httpd         
tcp        1      0 ::1:40287                   ::1:8009                    CLOSE_WAIT  32433/httpd
```

I cant figure out where my issue is.  Is it with the apache configuration or with the tomcat configuration or it is a coding issue...  I believe it is an configuration issue...  Please help me..

Comment: What's the port your tomcat is configured to listen to?

Comment: My tomcat is configured to 8080 and 8443 for SSL and  I have also ajp '<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got two problem after fixing it tomcat is not crashing..

1. Got bad sectors in Hardisk.. I found in messages log so java was crashing..
2. I got old quartz schedulers running.. I deleted that then now the tomcat is not crashing..