# Spring boot application gives 503 Service unavailable in the first minute

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

After my application starts up I see this message in the log:

```
Started Application in 22.609 seconds (JVM running for 24.342)
```

but when I access the application in the browser I get a 503 error for a certain period of time. Not always the same, so not likely a timeout.

Is this normal? What is taking so long? How can I debug this?

Great idea to access port 8080 directly. Here I get a different behavior: The browser waits and after some time I see this:
2017-11-10 09:40:37,276 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase - Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [88,709] milliseconds.
I'll try -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom now

Comment: Are you accessing your application directly to the Tomcat instance or via Apache? Also, do you have any other errors in your log?

Answer (score 0):

That solved it: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

Comment: Oh no. That solved ONE problem. But I still have to wait for some time. Sometimes up to a minute

Comment: This finally solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683052/why-am-i-getting-an-apache-proxy-503-error